# Lack of User Account Interface Manager in Xfce Desktop Manager

Tags: debian, users, xfce, gui

Recently installed Xfce altogether with Debian 10 "Buster", but having trouble with user management actions, like change portrait picture, user adding, removing user or changing password, on graphical user interface, having success only in command-line.

Isn't there by default any graphical user interface manager, and if doesn't, isn't there any package which manages it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except for the profile picture, what you want to do is normally done through the "Users and Groups" dialog. If for some reason it's unavailable through your GUI, it can be run from the command line with the command `system-config-users`. If the command's not found, you should be able to install it from your repo.

As far as I know, no one's yet gotten around to adding a profile picture setting feature to "Users and Groups". To change the picture, make the picture a png image (other types may work as well), name it `.face` (with no further extension), and put it in your home directory (i.e. `~/`). If the image is too large or not equal in height & width, Xfce shrinks the image as needed to fit. I'm not sure if there are any size limits on the image.

To change the image on the login screen, you'll need to provide an image (with an ordinary name and extension) that's accessable by LightDM, and then set the User image in the LightDM GTK+ Greeter settings to that image. The image can be put in `/home` if your user home directory is encrypted, and the permissions may need to be set to make it readable by LightDM. You'll need to install `lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings` from your repo if the Greeter settings item isn't available in Xfce's Settings.

I originally picked up info on changing the profile and login screen pictures from the video [How to set an account image in XFCE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m3kWAj3-IgQ), with relevant stuff really starting at about 1:20.

Comment: There's no `system-config-users` command or package in Ubuntu 22 repository.

Comment: @DavidFerenczyRogožan OP's question pertained to Debian, not Ubuntu, and I don't have a machine running Ubuntu to test on. Nevertheless, `system-config-users` is no longer available on my Fedora \w XFCE system either, so I'm currently using `MATE User Manager` for the same purpose. Seems to work fine even though I'm running Fedora rather than Mint and XFCE rather than MATE, but YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't exist a user config tool in pure xfce desktop, but you can use another. Personally I like gnome and it integrates nicely with xfce.

Install the gnome system if you want users-admin

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-system-tools
```

or the kde system if you want the KDE user tool

```
sudo apt-get install kuser
```

Comment: `gnome-system-tools` actually comes installed by default in *Xubuntu*, providing `users-admin`, which integrates neatly into the native XFCE settings window/menu. It has a clean, non-bloat interface with just the right amount of features.